# UDP socket: error 34 but works fine

Tags: sockets, udp

I have a recvfrom returning error 34, I have checked and it means "Numerical result out of range" but after it is receiving correctly the data and also the amount of data received is correct. I think it may crash after some time. Here i show the call to recvfrom:

```
int dataRCV = -55;

    dataRCV = recvfrom ( sockfd2, data_CPV, sizeData_CPV, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr2,&client_addresslen2);

fprintf(%i %s, dataRCV,sterror(errno));
```

Thanks

Comment: It isn't valid to use `errno` in any way unless the immediately prior system call has returned -1.

Answer (score 1):

`recvfrom()` returns the number of bytes read, not an error code.  If `recvfrom()` fails, it will return -1 and `errno` will report the actual error code.

```
int dataRCV = recvfrom ( sockfd2, data_CPV, sizeData_CPV, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr2, &client_addresslen2);
if (dataRCV == -1)
    fprintf(%i %s, errno, sterror(errno));
```

So if `dataRCV` is being set to 34 then `recvfrom()` has successfully read 34 bytes, not failed.